# Specific C character unknown

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand the following code but there is something I've never seen before which is this: "`\&\&`"

here is the code :

```
int main() {
fork() \&\& (fork() || fork());
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
```

What does the code do?

Comment: This is not valid C.

Comment: I've also never seen.

Comment: Maybe an artifact of some weird copy+paste and started as `fork() && (fork() || fork());`? Which is still a weird line of c....

Comment: @tinkertime: "*weird line of c*" ya, student torturing ...

Comment: "*What does the code do?*" it doesn't compile.

Comment: *To fork() or not to fork(), that is the question...*

Comment: Well, the original code from the teacher text is really like that. But he may have done a copy+paste.
It is supposed to duplicate process, and the question is how many process. 
It doesn't compile because of the line 2

Answer (score 0):

In the case where your teacher write `fork() && (fork() || fork());`:

`fork()` create a new process and return the `pid_t` of the new processes if you are the parent or `0` if you are the child or `-1` if they are errors.

There are a lot of possibilities, I will ignore that `fork()` can `return` error.

The main process call `fork()` and it's `return` `0` in the child, this stop the logical `&&`, the first child `return`. The parent has a positive value so it calls a second `fork()`. Here this is a `||` so the parent stop here and `return`. The second child call the next `fork()` and then `return`. The third child `return` too because they are no more instruction.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot :)

Comment: So, correct if I'm wrong, the first fork() creates 3 children process ? Like 1 parents and 3 children ?

Comment: @LyessDrille the first process create two child and the second child create a third child.

Comment: Sorry I meant  I wish I could draw something,  but we have something like : process 1 creates process 2, process 2 stop. process 1 creates process 3, process 1 stop. process 3 creates process 4